# how to put an iframe with 'transform:scale' to the left side

Tags: html, css, iframe

So I have this iframe and without any 'transform:scale' css it displays on top-left side of the div but after I add

```
-webkit-transform:scale(0.6,1);
margin-left:0.0em;
```

to its css property It automatically scales it self to the center which I really do not want it too do.

Here is my jsfiddle link : [JS Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/686rN/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform-origin), like this:

```
-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
-webkit-transform:scale(0.6,1);
```

The default value is `50% 50%`, which is why you are seeing the `iframe` appear to shift into the centre of your `div`.

[Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/fzWW3/), including all the other prefixed versions you should include.